# Problem with cascading Telerik grid's edit functionality

Tags: grid, telerik

I am faceing a serious issue with Telerik Extension grid. There are three Telerik grids on my page with select ,edit and delete command button. Intially fist grid is populated, after selecting record from first grid second grid is getting populated and so on..

To achive this I have created seprate ActionResult(ex: selectFirstGrid, selectSecondGrid...) for each grid. It's is working fine. but edit functionality of grid is not working .

Please can any body provide me example code.

Comment: What specific isn't working?  Check out demos.telerik.com for a demonstration...

Answer (score 0):

No one at SO is going to write code for you. That is not the purpose of this site. Browse the examples located here: [http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/...](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/default/defaultcs.aspx)

They also have a great forum and support community. You can find that here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums.aspx